# BigQuery - Count Conditionally

Tags: sql, count, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am looking to count the number of occurrences that exist before a row.

Table:

```
|day |time|type|1   |2   |3   |4   |
|Mon |9   |A   |a1  |a2  |a3  |a4  |
|Mon |10  |B   |b1  |b2  |b3  |b4  |
|Mon |12  |A   |c1  |c2  |c3  |c4  |
|Mon |20  |C   |d1  |d2  |d3  |d4  |
|Tue |9   |A   |e1  |e2  |e3  |e4  |
|Tue |10  |B   |f1  |f2  |f3  |f4  |
|Tue |11  |B   |g1  |g2  |g3  |g4  |
|Tue |12  |C   |h1  |h2  |h3  |h4  |
|Wed |9   |A   |i1  |i2  |i3  |i4  |
```

Output:

```
|day |time|type|1   |2   |3   |4   |#A  |
|Mon |9   |A   |a1  |a2  |a3  |a4  |0   |
|Mon |10  |B   |b1  |b2  |b3  |b4  |1   |
|Mon |12  |A   |c1  |c2  |c3  |c4  |1   |
|Mon |20  |C   |d1  |d2  |d3  |d4  |2   |
|Tue |9   |A   |e1  |e2  |e3  |e4  |0   |
|Tue |10  |B   |f1  |f2  |f3  |f4  |1   |
|Tue |11  |B   |g1  |g2  |g3  |g4  |1   |
|Tue |12  |C   |h1  |h2  |h3  |h4  |1   |
|Wed |9   |A   |i1  |i2  |i3  |i4  |0   |
```

I have attempted to perform

```
select
x.day,x.time,x.type,x.1,x.2,x.3,x.4,count(*) as #A
from
Table as x
left outer join 
Table(where type=A) as y
on
y.day = x.day
and
y.time < x.time
group by
x.day,x.time,x.type,x.1,x.2,x.3,x.4
```

but this is not giving me the right answer with #A being too low.

The table is pretty large with more than 30M rows and over 50k of type A with order by causing my memory limit to bounce, is not helping debug the errors...

I also need this the be run as a scheduled job, I have considered using dataflow or dataprep to help but i would prefer to solve it purely in BigQuery.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm attempting to debug the query on a smaller dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  COUNTIF(type = 'A') OVER(
    PARTITION BY day ORDER BY time ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
  ) Count_of_A
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result as

```
Row day time    type    col1    col2    col3    col4    Count_of_A   
1   Mon 9       A       a1      a2      a3      a4      0    
2   Mon 10      B       b1      b2      b3      b4      1    
3   Mon 12      A       c1      c2      c3      c4      1    
4   Mon 20      C       d1      d2      d3      d4      2    
5   Tue 9       A       e1      e2      e3      e4      0    
6   Tue 10      B       f1      f2      f3      f4      1    
7   Tue 11      B       g1      g2      g3      g4      1    
8   Tue 12      C       h1      h2      h3      h4      1    
9   Wed 9       A       i1      i2      i3      i4      0
```